# Can I extend a function in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, typescript, closures

I want to create my super awesome container class that holds a single value.

```
let a = new Container(42);
```

An I want to get values like this

```
a(); // 42
```

and set values like this

```
a(43);
```

Is there a way to achieve this in TypeScript?

Comment: Sounds like what properties are for.

Answer (score 2):

Operator overloading is not properly supported in JavaScript / TypeScript.
You cannot define functions (except constructors) which are called if you try to call a class.

Comment: Its true that there is no real operation overloading, but you still can do some - for sure limited - stuff that is similar to operation overloading [here an example](https://jsfiddle.net/gvo86g6c/).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to achieve this in TypeScript?

Why not. For it can be done in plain JavaScript, it easily should be achieved in TypeScript too. As almost always with Functions, *scope* is the keyword for our approach.
A constructor then of course gets misused just as a closure without creating types that would respond to e.g. `Container` via the `typeof` operator. Such a factory function will just return another function that then is used as getter/setter for the constructor's enclosed initial value.

TypeScript example ...

```
class Container {

    constructor(storageValue: any)  {
        return (function (value: any) {

            if (arguments.length !== 0) {
                storageValue = value;
            }
            return storageValue;
        });
    }
}
```

... in plain JavaScript ...

```
var Container = (function ContainerClass () {

    var Constructor = (function Container (storageValue) {
        return (function (value) {

            if (arguments.length !== 0) {
                storageValue = value;
            }
            return storageValue;
        });
    });
    return Constructor;

}());

var a = new Container(24);

console.log("a() : ", a());   // 24
console.log("a(4) : ", a(4)); //  4
console.log("a() : ", a());   //  4

var b = new Container(72);

console.log("b() : ", b());   // 72
console.log("b(5) : ", b(5)); //  5
console.log("b() : ", b());   //  5

console.log("a() : ", a());   //  4
```

Comment: Instead of `if (UNDEFINED_VALUE !== value) {` it might be better to use `arguments.length===0`,  because `a()` and `a(undefined)`  are two different things.

Comment: It's not type safe. There is no point using TypeScript if you put `any` everywhere.

Comment: I leave it open to the OP deciding about the type that is going to be stored inside a `Container`. From it's given example one could assume `Number`.